# Let M be invariant under L. If x+y $\in$ M, where L(x) = $\lambda$x, L(y) = $\mu$y, and $\lambda$ does not equal $\mu$, then x, y $\in$ M.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let L: V $\rightarrow$ V be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space and M $\subset$ V an invariant subspace. If x+y $\in$ M, where L(x) = $\lambda$x, L(y) = $\mu$y, and $\lambda$ does not equal $\mu$, then x, y $\in$ M.

My final solution:

Since M is invariant, we have L(x + y) $\in$ M and, since L is linear, we have L(x + y) = L(x) + L(y) = $\lambda$x + $\mu$y $\in$ M. Since x+y $\in$ M and M is a vector space, all scalar multiples of x+y are also in M. Thus, $\lambda$x + $\mu$y - $\lambda$(x+y) = $\mu$y - $\lambda$y = ($\mu$ - $\lambda$)y $\in$ M. Since $\mu$ does not equal $\lambda$, we have $\mu$ - $\lambda$ != 0 and so the inverse of $\mu$ - $\lambda$ exists. Thus, y $\in$ M. Similarly, we have -$\mu$(x+y) $\in$ M implies x $\in$ M.

Comment: $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are given, you cannot just change them at will; so you're proof is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I expected this wouldn't work, but I guess I was hoping it would. How should I approach this problem? I am genuinely stuck at this point. I don't want the answer, but I need help seeing the direction I need to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're proof is wrong because $\lambda,\mu$ are given and you cannot just change them as you wish.

But you were on the right track: $L(x+y)=\lambda x+\mu y\in M$ because $M$ is invariant. Since also $x+y\in M$, also linear combinations of $\lambda x+\mu y$ and $x+y$ are in $M$.

Which linear combination could you make to obtain just a multiple of $x$ or $y$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is such a simple problem but I just wasn't thinking clearly. Sorry to have wasted your time, and thank you again.